# How to name each city in a matplotlib/geopandas map from csv file?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, maps, geopandas

I have a csv file containing the cities in senegal, theres a city column, i have already used the long and lat columns to plot the points, but now id like to have each point have its city name next to it, and maybe later more information. how can i do this with matplotlib? thank you.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import pandas as pd

file = os.path.join("senegal_administrative","senegal_administrative.shp")

cities_file = os.path.join("senegal_administrative","sn.csv")

cities = pd.read_csv(cities_file)
senegal = gpd.read_file(file)

## THE MAP IS PLOTED HERE
axis = senegal.plot(color="lightblue",edgecolor = "black",figsize = (20,20))

def_geo = gpd.GeoDataFrame(cities,geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(cities.lng,cities.lat))
print(def_geo)

## I PLOT THE POINTS HERE
def_geo.plot(ax = axis,color = "black")

plt.show()
```

heres a dropbox link if you need the files, i really appreciate it : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dr54pbc9a5zc5ke/AADMxnYHe4maAnwKArCsh1m8a?dl=0
[image]

Comment: Use `axis.annotate()` to plot annotation. Run `help(axis.annotate)` to see help document.

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?

Comment: oh man im sorry there,annotate was the fix! i completly forgot to comeback and mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To annotate the map, you can use `.annotate()` function.
Here is the relevant parts of the code:

```
axis = senegal.plot(color="lightblue",edgecolor = "black",figsize = (12,12))
for idx,dat in cities.iterrows():
    #print(dat.city, dat.lng, dat.lat)
    axis.scatter(dat.lng, dat.lat, s=10, color='red')
    axis.annotate(dat.city, (dat.lng, dat.lat))
```

Plot will be similar to this:

[image: senegal]

Comment: yeah i actually managed to make it work,but i forgot to mention it here because i got stuck on another task sadly, im trying to figure out how to show a small graph next to each point everytime the user hovers on a city, if thats even possible. but thank you!

Comment: @Dems314 If you need interactive (web) map, look for `folium`, https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/index.html. Folium popup is very good for data visualization.

Comment: sadly ou assignement requires us to not use any WEB tools, thats why its a big headache for me.